# Auto Layout extra spacing

Tags: ios, autolayout

I set my UI elements with offsets 0(left), 0(right). However, there are extra spacing on this sides. Please take a look at screen:

[image]

How to fix that?

Comment: Either set it to -20 or better uncheck "constrain to margin" or similar.

Comment: @HAS where to uncheck this?

Comment: When creating the constraints or click on the created ones and in the inspector somewhere (sorry I'm on mobile currently).

Comment: Yeah Adrian has a screenshot in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to make sure you don't have Constrain to Margins ticked when you set your constraint.

I've attached a screen shot.

[image]

Comment: thanks! That is why i prefer libs like Masonry to deal with auto layout, instead of Storyboards..